# Django 2.0.5 - Signature of method 'ContentCreateUpdateView.dispatch()' does not match signature of base method in class 'View'

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and I am following a book project Django 2 by example. In one of there project "building an elearning site", the have the following code:

```
class ContentCreateUpdateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    module = None
    model = None
    obj = None
    template_name = 'courses/manage/content/form.html'

    def get_model(self, model_name):
        if model_name in ['text', 'video', 'image', 'file']:
            return apps.get_model(app_label='courses', model_name=model_name)
        return None

    def get_form(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        Form = modelform_factory(model, exclude=['owner', 'order', 'created', 'updated'])
        return Form(*args, **kwargs)

    def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        self.module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=module_id, course__owner=request.user)
        self.model = self.get_model(model_name)

        if id:
            self.obj = get_object_or_404(self.model, id=id, owner=request.user)

        return super(ContentCreateUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, module_id, model_name, id)

    def get(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj)
        return self.render_to_response({ 'form':form, 'object': self.obj })

    def post(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
        form = self.get_form(self.model, instance=self.obj, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            if not id:
                Content.objects.create(module=self.module, item=obj)
            return redirect('module_content_list', self.module.id)

        return self.render_to_response({'form': form, 'object': self.obj })
```

But I am getting an error message from PyCharm (my IDE) on:

```
def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):
```

And the error is:

```
Signature of method 'ContentCreateUpdateView.dispatch()' does not match signature of base method in class 'View' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection detects inconsistencies in overriding method signatures.
```

Is there a way for me to troubleshoot the issue and see how to begin fixing the error? What is Pycharm even trying to tell me??
I am using python 3 and DJango 2.0.5

Answer (score 1):

The warning is telling you that `def dispatch(self, request, module_id, model_name, id=None):` in your class is different to `def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` in the [`View`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/71d9876e39abafe81e031b92ecd300c7d13346ea/django/views/generic/base.py#L93) class.

However, since the method in the `View` class accepts `*args` and `**kwargs`, it won't cause any problems when you actually run the code, so you can ignore it.

If it was your own code, I would consider using `*args` and `**kwargs` in your method as well.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    module_id = kwargs['module_id']
    self.module = get_object_or_404(Module, id=module_id, course__owner=request.user)
    ...
```

However, since you're following a book, I think you'll hit fewer problems if you follow the code exactly.